# Longest Increasing Subsequence problem (leetcode)

Tags: c++, dynamic-programming

link of the problem:

[link]https://leetcode.com/problems/longest-increasing-subsequence/

```
class Solution {
public:
int lengthOfLIS(vector& nums)
{
int n=nums.size();
if (n==0)
return 0;

    int list[n];
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
        list[i]=0;
    
    list[0]=1;
    for(int i=1;i<n;i++)
    {
        for(int j=i-1;j>=0;j--)
        {
            if(nums[j]<nums[i])
                list[i]=max(list[i],1+list[j]);
        }
    }
    int ans=1;
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
        ans=max(ans,list[i]);
    return ans;
}
};
```

Input: `[10,9,2,5,3,7,101,18]`

output is coming:`3`

expected output:`4`

not getting it where its wrong.

Comment: Did you debug it? Did you go through it step-by-step on paper? In theory, this should just take time, not knowledge...

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings i did all those stuffs i am getting 4 as my ans but compiler says 3

Comment: The question is stupid because if you're looking for a subsequence then it should inherently be a continuous subsequence. Anyway, I don't understand this statement: list[i]=max(list[i],1+list[j]); You should initialize the array to 1 by filling in all values to 1. The subtle point that's being missed is that for each subsequence you want to test each value wrt to the min value in the subsequence. I'm submitted a working solution below together with a few test cases.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <sstream>

class Solution
{
public:
  int lengthOfLIS(std::vector<int> &);
  int max(int, int);
  std::string print(std::vector<int> const &);
};

int Solution::max(int a, int b)
{
  return a < b ? b : a;
}

std::string Solution::print(std::vector<int> const &input)
{
  std::stringstream ss;
    for (int i = 0; i < input.size(); i++)
        ss << input.at(i) << ' ';

  return ss.str();
}

int Solution::lengthOfLIS(std::vector<int> &nums)
{
  int n = nums.size();
  
  if (n == 0)
    return 0;

  int list[n];
  std::fill_n(list, n, 1);
  //list[0] = 1;

  for (int i = 1; i < n; i++)
  {
    int min_val = nums[i];

    for (int j = i - 1; j > -1; j--)
    {
      if (nums[j] < nums[i] && nums[j] < min_val)
      {
        list[i]++;
        min_val = nums[j];
      }
    }
  }

  int ans = 1;

  for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    ans = max(ans, list[i]);

  return ans;
}

int main()
{
  std::vector<int> Input0 { 10, 9, 2, 5, 3, 7, 101, 18 },
    Input1 { 10, 19, 2, 5, 3, 7, 101, 18 },
    Input2 { 10, 9, 12, 5, 3, 7, 101, 18 },
    Input3 { 10, 9, 2, 15, 3, 7, 101, 18 },
    Input4 { 10, 9, 2, 5, 13, 7, 101, 18 },
    Input5 { 10, 9, 2, 5, 3, 17, 101, 18 },
    Input6 { 10, 9, 2, 5, 13, 7, 10, 18 },
    Input7 { 10, 9, 2, 5, 13, 7, 101, 180 };
  Solution solution;
  std::cout << solution.print(Input0) << "\t|\t" << solution.lengthOfLIS(Input0) << std::endl;
  std::cout << solution.print(Input1) << "\t|\t" << solution.lengthOfLIS(Input1) << std::endl;
  std::cout << solution.print(Input2) << "\t|\t" << solution.lengthOfLIS(Input2) << std::endl;
  std::cout << solution.print(Input3) << "\t|\t" << solution.lengthOfLIS(Input3) << std::endl;
  std::cout << solution.print(Input4) << "\t|\t" << solution.lengthOfLIS(Input4) << std::endl;
  std::cout << solution.print(Input5) << "\t|\t" << solution.lengthOfLIS(Input5) << std::endl;
  std::cout << solution.print(Input6) << "\t|\t" << solution.lengthOfLIS(Input6) << std::endl;
  std::cout << solution.print(Input7) << "\t|\t" << solution.lengthOfLIS(Input7) << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks buddy fr the ans but i wanna say this again, i just want to find fault in my solution.

Comment: This test if(nums[j]<nums[i]) is insufficient. You need to test for the minimum value in each subsequence. You should also initialize the array list to ones because for each element in the sequence there is at least one value regardless of whether the sequence is increasing/decreasing. The function lengthOfLIS is matched line by line with yours, so I hope you can see what I'm describing here.

Answer (score 1):

There is just a slight error in your code, every time you are accessing a new index (i.e on each iteration of i), the longest increasing subsequence that can be found for an index is that element itself.

So for each iteration intially you should set
`list[i] = 1`

Or, you can also initialize every element as 1 in list array.

```
class Solution {
public:
    int lengthOfLIS(vector<int>& nums) {
        int n=nums.size();
        if (n==0)
            return 0;

        int list[n];
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
            list[i]=0;

        list[0]=1;
        for(int i=1;i<n;i++) {
            list[i] = 1;
            for(int j=i-1;j>=0;j--) {
                if(nums[j]<nums[i])
                list[i]=max(list[i],1+list[j]);
            }
        }
        int ans=1;
        
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
            ans=max(ans,list[i]);
        return ans;
    }
};
```

Answer (score -1):

Using `std::lower_bound`, this'd pass:

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

static const struct Solution {
    static const int lengthOfLIS(
        const std::vector<int> &nums
    ) {
        std::vector<int> longest;

        for (std::size_t index = 0; index < nums.size(); index++) {
            const auto iter = std::lower_bound(longest.begin(), longest.end(), nums[index]);

            if (iter == longest.end()) {
                longest.emplace_back(nums[index]);

            } else {
                *iter = nums[index];
            }
        }

        return longest.size();
    }
};
```

---

### References

- For additional details, please see the [Discussion Board](https://leetcode.com/problems/longest-increasing-subsequence/discuss/) where you can find plenty of well-explained accepted solutions with a variety of [languages](https://support.leetcode.com/hc/en-us/articles/360011833974-What-are-the-environments-for-the-programming-languages-) including low-complexity algorithms and asymptotic [runtime](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity)/[memory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_complexity) analysis<sup>[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation), [2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analysis_of_algorithms)</sup>.

Comment: What is a `static const struct`? Why should a function return `const int`?

Comment: i don't want ans buddy i just need my code to be inspected and check where it is wrong